# Div Element act like a background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I make a `<div>` element act like a background like the intro of this web [jabarprov.go.id](http://jabarprov.go.id)?

This is my codepen 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGEmxB

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
         $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
         $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
      });
     });
```

```css
#div1, #div2{
       height:100vh;
      }
      
      #div1{background-color:cyan}
      #div2{background-color:lightgrey}
      
      nav {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
       background: Green;
       padding:2px 0;
       z-index:1;
      }
      
      .fixed {
       position: fixed; 
       top: 0; 
       height: 70px; 
       z-index: 1;
      }
      section {
       height: 100vh;
      }

      /* Screens Settings */
      #screen1 { 
       background: #43b29d;
      }

      #screen1 p {
       padding-top: 200px;
      }

      #screen2 {
       background: #efc94d;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <div id="div1" class="col-md-3">LEFT SECTION</div>
        <div id="div2" class="col-md-9">RIGHT SECTION</div>
     <nav class="main-bg">
         <div class="container">
       NAVIGATION HERE
      </div>
     </nav>
     <section id="screen2"></section>
     <section id="screen3"></section>
```

The problem is the intro my page is not fixed (acts like fixed background).

Comment: which want you set as background ??  can you explain a little bit more ??

Comment: the #div1 and #div2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code.
Hope it is what you searched for
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaLGrp

I made a wrapper around div1 and 2 which is fixed and made change to sizes

wrapper

```
<div id="intro-wrapper">
  <div id="div1" class="col-md-3">a</div>
  <div id="div2" class="col-md-9">b</div>
</div>
```

wrapper css and sizes

```
body{
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
#intro-wrapper{
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}
#div1, #div2{
  height:calc(100vh - 70px);
}
```

navigation position

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100vh - 70px);
  width: 100%;
  background: Green;
  padding:2px 0;
  z-index:1;
  height:70px;
}
```

Comment: but if i create an <a> tag inside the #intro-wrapper it will be unclickable

Comment: I've updated codepen. Please check changes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaLGrp

Now it's perfectly clickable